# Spring, Why does the controller work 3 times?

Tags: spring, maven, model-view-controller

I finished the initial setup using a combination of Spring Framework + Maven.

No special work was done and only minimal installation was performed.

It consists of one most basic controller and one JSP (basic index) file.

So when I run the server, the System.out.println statement I wrote down as an example in the controller is executed a total of 3 times.

Why is that?

```
@Controller
public class mainController {

@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String main() {

    System.out.println("why?");
    return "index";
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by “run the server”? Are you using an embedded server or external? Does this get printed on startup or upon visiting the endpoint?

Comment: Mapping to `/` basically means everything, so each request will goto this controller. So depending on what you do on your `index.jsp` (like trying to load images, resources etc) this will be executed multiple times.

Comment: Use the built-in server. The exact time of output is 1 when the built-in server is started and running, and 2 more times just before the web is opened after reaching the endpoint, for a total of 3 times.